How to create an InlineButton that will show Share menu in Telegram?
Recently I have seen this button that call share with menu in Telegram. I need this method in inline keyboard.
I tried it:
InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("test1", url=link, request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestUser(1, chat_is_channel=True)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("test2", url=link, request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestUser(2, chat_is_channel=True)),
        ]
    ]

This doesn’t work. What can I do?
[


If I set url - this starts the bot, if I set callback_data - there’s no action
